# Antialiased bezier curve with GDI / Winforms - c# .net

Tags: .net, gdi, antialiasing, bezier, curve

I'm trying to paint a bezier curve in a sample Winforms application.

I'm calculating the bezier points, and then painting using DrawImage to draw a custom image brush on each point.

However I'm not exactly getting the result I was hoping for - the resulting curve is not smooth at the points that it bends (note the Y coordinates are increased / decreased with 1px):

[image: Choppy curve]

Here is an example of a "nice" curve quickly painted in "photoshop" with the brush tool:

[image: Nice curve]

Does anyone know how to achieve this kind of "antialiasing"?

I'm basically doing this:

```
        using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            //points - an array with calculated beziere curve points
            //image - the "image brush" that is painted at each curve point
            foreach (var p in points)
            {
                g.DrawImage(image, p);
                g.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Erm, wait, DrawImage to draw a bezier?  Use DrawBezier with a Pen that has a TextureBrush.

Comment: Hi, yes - I tried that initially, however when the curve bends, the texture doesn't follow the bend - it just simply tiles the texture as the background. Unless I have missed some configuration?

Comment: Right, you can't get that out of the Graphics class.  I'm not aware of a common graphics library that can do this.  Nobody would buy Photoshop if it was easy, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting this because your `points` collection contains structs of type `Point`, which uses `Int32` - as a result, you're quantizing your points yourself.

Try using `PointF` instead - this allows you to draw images at any arbitrary location, instead of being quantized around integer locations.

Comment: This is another example of how horrible `var` is. When used in a line like `for each (var p in Points)`, it accomplishes nothing other than obscuring the object/struct type, which in this case just obscures the source of the problem.

Comment: True, however in this case I would say it was "shit behind the wheels" that caused the problem :) - I actually didn't even know you could get more precision than pixels on the screen, so why would int or float matter :) - I did make sure that the transitions were no more than 1px in either X / Y... but apparently there is some magic behind the scenes there :O

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using GDI to draw lines and so your Smoothing and InterpolationMode settings have no effect. You're simply drawing an image per every point in a point array and so there's no connecting those points or any kind of antialiasing. Try converting your points collection into a path and using [g.DrawPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath.aspx) to draw your curve.

A simpler, though Bezier-less, example of this would be to use the [DrawLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines.aspx) method. Something like:

```
g.DrawLines(Pens.Blue, points.ToArray());
```

You don't even need a loop for DrawLines and DrawPath. DrawLines is like a poor man's DrawPath...